Does Visual Studio Code have keyboard shortcuts that toggle the suggestion details and explain mode popups on a suggestions
When I activate suggestions by pressing ctrl+space, I get a list of suggestions and Javadoc for the highlighted suggestion.
suggestion list with javadoc popup for highlighted suggestion
If I click the X - circled in red - the popup is hidden and won't appear next time I activate suggestions.
suggestion list with no javadoc popup
The only way I have found to restore the javadoc popup is to mouse over to the end of the highlighted suggestion and click on the Read More icon - circled in red.
suggestion list with Read More icon
Does Visual Studio Code have keyboard shortcuts, or can I create shortcuts, that will hide and restore the Javadoc popup?
I have searched settings and keyboard shortcuts and haven't found any predefined shortcuts

vscode doesn't have a built-in shortcut to hide and unhide the javadoc popup. You can use Ctrl+Space to trigger it. Or create a custom shortcut. Start by selecting the File, open Preferences, and tap on the keyboard shortcuts.
In the page that opens, select the Open keyboard shortcuts (JSON) button. You can add custom shortcuts to the file. For example:
  {
        "key": "Ctrl+Shift+J",
        "command": "toggleJavadoc",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }


Thanks @Jeanneli. After applying your answer, I get a warning, "command 'toggleJavadoc' not found". I can see all the available commands in the Command column of the keyboard shortcuts page. "toggleJavadoc" is listed with the keybinding. However, if I take out the JSON above, the command is no longer listed in the Command column.
So, for this solution to work, I would need to map the keybinding to an existing command listed in the table?

I've found my answers. The command is toggleSuggestionDetails bound to ctrl+space. Once I use ctrl+space to Trigger suggest, I just have to use ctrl+space to toggle suggestion details on (show) and off (hide).

In my case, I also added the bindings below so that ctrl+/ will hide the suggest widget. I find that easier than the default binding of esc  (sorry - code format didnt work)
{
"key": "ctrl+/",
"command": "-toggleExplainMode",
"when": "suggestWidgetVisible"
},
{
"key": "ctrl+/",
"command": "hideSuggestWidget",
"when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
{
"key": "shift+escape",
"command": "-hideSuggestWidget",
"when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
}
